# How can I apply a theme to all the tableViews in my app at once?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, uitableview, themes

I am currently coding an app that has a fair number of tableViews. I am now at the closing stages of the process and am theming the app. Currently it is easy to alter a single tableView to trial my ideas but I am struggling to alter all the tableViews in the entire app in one go.

Would my best approach to be to go into the app delegate and add some custom code into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

```
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setBackgroundView:customThemedView];
```

Adding something like this seems to mess with my custom TableViewCells

Would it be possible to create a special tableView, which would be a subclass of uitableview, which could inherit its attributes to the other tableViews in the app?

Comment: I would create a uitableview subclass, say, themedtableview.  When it's loaded, theme it. Take it a step further and have it respond to some sort of theme change notification, and refresh it with the new theme when you post the notification somewhere in your app.

Comment: you could write a category.. this will effect all the UITableViews

Answer (score 0):

You do need to set your appearance proxies in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`. However you can make sure that only selected controllers get this style by using `appearanceWhenContainedIn` instead.

For example, in the following example, only `UITableViewCell`s inside `MyViewController` will get this particular style.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableViewCell appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyViewController class], nil];
//TODO: Set your cell's custom appearance
```